# mysql polygon search fails

Tags: mysql, search, gis, polygon

In my table I have three geospatial fields:

```
`lat` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
`lon` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
`location` point NOT NULL,
```

And three geospatial indices:

```
KEY `lat` (`lat`),
KEY `lon` (`lon`),
SPATIAL KEY `location` (`location`)
```

I then have a trigger defined as 'on before update' which sets the `location` from the lat/lon pair like this:

```
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.location = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',NEW.lat,' ',NEW.lon,')'))
```

I'm pretty certain the data is correct because I can do all sorts of circle queries.  Now, I also need to do some polygon queries and just can't get it to return any results! Here's my polygon query:

```
SET @bbox = 'POLYGON((32.70 -117.16, 47.97 -122.19, 44.80 -68.77, 25.77 -80.19, 32.70 -117.16))';
SELECT * , AsText( location ) 
FROM geo_table
WHERE Intersects( location, GeomFromText( @bbox ) );
```

Running this query through phpMyAdmin I get the following message for both SQL statements:

```
# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

As an FYI, the data points shown in the above SET @bbox are from 4 corners of the US (entered clockwise) and should return 99% of all points but returns nothing.  Here are the coordinates:
San Diego, CA: +32.70 -117.16
Seatle, WA: 47.97 -122.19
Bangor, Maine: 44.80 -68.77 
Miami, FL: 25.77 -80.19

I have also tried this against over 3500 polygons from the NWS CAP 1.1 feed and I get nothing!  I figure I must be doing something wrong but, for the life of me, I can't figure out what it is!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use Intersects, try with [Contains](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_contains) instead.

```
SET @bbox = 'POLYGON((32.70 -117.16, 47.97 -122.19, 44.80 -68.77, 25.77 -80.19, 32.70 -117.16))';
SET @USA = GeomFromText(@bbox);
SET @Lincoln = PointFromText('POINT(40.82 -96.71)');
SELECT Contains(@USA, @Lincoln);
```